# Separate equation, figure and table counters inside "comment" environment

Tags: floats, equations, environments

I'm using the LaTeX package `comment` in an Overleaf project in order to share comments with teammates.

I'd like to find a way for the equations, figures and tables that are created within a special comment environment to have separate counters from the rest of the document. This is in order to leave the counters of the main document unchanged whenever a comment is deleted or added. Is that possible?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\specialcomment{comm}{ % This is my special comment environment
    \begingroup % Some styling
        \itshape
        \small
}
{
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Einstein said:

\begin{equation} % This equation will be numbered (1)
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{comm} % Beginning of my comment
    It's true but in general:
    
    \begin{equation} % This equation will be numbered (2) but I'd like it to be numbered otherwise, e.g. (I) or (C.1)
        E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + p^2c^2}
    \end{equation}
\end{comm}

Therefore:

\begin{equation} % This equation will be numbered (3) but I'd like it to continue from the last equation *outside* of the comm environment, i.e. (2) in this case
    c = \sqrt{\frac{E}{m}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The produced output is:

[image: Output produced by MWE posted above]

The desired output would be:

[image: Desired output]

Thank you in advance for your answers!
Best regards

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Don't know if I'm supposed to answer here but thank you :)

Comment: You can use `\tag{C.1}` for nonsequantial equation numbers.  Also, figues and tables don't have numbers: only captions have numbers.

Comment: Hi @JohnKormylo and thanks for your answer. If I understand the usage of `\tag` it would be something I should add every time I write a new equation in the `comm` environment? If so, then I'd like to avoid this type of solution and ideally I'd like for this "special numbering" to be produced automatically whenever I am in such an environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the new counter.  You could replace `figure` and `table` as well, but you would probably want a new counter for each.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\newcounter{comment}
\renewcommand{\thecomment}{C.\arabic{comment}}
\makeatletter
\specialcomment{comm}{ % This is my special comment environment
    \begingroup % Some styling
        \itshape
        \small
        \let\c@equation=\c@comment
        \let\theequation=\thecomment
}
{
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Einstein said:

\begin{equation} % This equation will be numbered (1)
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{comm} % Beginning of my comment
    It's true but in general:
    
    \begin{equation} % This equation will be numbered (2) but I'd like it to be numbered otherwise, e.g. (I) or (C.1)
        E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + p^2c^2}
    \end{equation}
\end{comm}

Therefore:

\begin{equation} % This equation will be numbered (3) but I'd like it to continue from the last equation *outside* of the comm environment, i.e. (2) in this case
    c = \sqrt{\frac{E}{m}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I wanted! Accepted answer. Thank you!!